# Resampling raw audio with NAudio

Tags: c#, naudio

I'd like to resample audio: change its sample rate from 44k to 11k. The input I've got is raw audio in bytes. It really is raw, it has no headers - if I try loading it into a `WaveFileReader`, I get an exception saying "Not a WAVE file - no RIFF header".

How I'm currently trying to achieve it is something like this (just a really simplified piece of code):

```cs
WaveFormat ResampleInputFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, 1);
WaveFormat ResampleOutputFormat = new WaveFormat(11025, 1);

MemoryStream ResampleInputMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();

foreach (var b in InputListOfBytes)
{
    ResampleInputMemoryStream.Write(new byte[]{b}, 0, 1);
}

RawSourceWaveStream ResampleInputWaveStream =
  new RawSourceWaveStream(ResampleInputMemoryStream, ResampleInputFormat);
WaveFormatConversionStream ResampleOutputStream =
  new WaveFormatConversionStream(ResampleOutputFormat, ResampleInputWaveStream);

byte[] bytes = new byte[2];
while (ResampleOutputStream.Read(bytes, 0, 2) > 0)
{
    OutputListOfBytes.Add(bytes[0]);
    OutputListOfBytes.Add(bytes[1]);
}
```

My problem is: the last loop is an infinite loop. The `Read()` always gets the same values and never advances in the Stream. I even tried `Seek()`-ing to the right position after each `Read()`, but that doesn't seem to work either, I still always get the same values.

What am I doing wrong? And is this even the right way to resample raw audio? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to reset ResampleInputMemoryStream's position to the start. It may actually have been easier to create the memory stream based on the array:

```
new MemoryStream(InputListOfBytes)
```

Second, when reading out of the resampler, you need to read in larger chunks than two bytes at a time. Try at least a second's worth of audio (use `ResampleOutputStream.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond`).

Comment: 1) Well, I may have simplified my code a bit too much, because I got rid of some details that I considered unnecessary - in fact, what I initially have is a List<short>, so I can't make a Stream of it unfortunately.
2) The NAudio.Wave.WaveFormatConversionStream does not have an AverageBytesPerSecond attribute. Is there any other way to get that value?
Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Sorry, it's a property of the WaveFormat property on your output stream. I'll amend my answer

Comment: Thanks, it's working. Now I've got another problem, but I'll mark this question answered as that's a different problem.